# How to compare two maps with different values using the Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

There are two maps and a method that accepts them and returns a new map.
Maps contain the same number of the same keys, but their values ​​are different.

```
    Map<String, Boolean> a = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Boolean> b = new HashMap<>();

    a.put("a", false);
    a.put("b", true);
    a.put("c", true);

    b.put("a", true);
    b.put("b", true);
    b.put("c", false);

public static Map<String, Boolean> getNewMap(Map<String, Boolean> a, Map<String, Boolean> b) 
{
    Map<String, Boolean> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> mapB : b.entrySet())
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> mapA : a.entrySet()) {
            if (mapB.getKey().equals(mapA.getKey()) && 
               !mapB.getValue().equals(mapA.getValue())) {
                newMap.put(mapB.getKey(), mapB.getValue());
            }
        }
    return newMap;
}
```

The method finds the same keys and writes the key and the different value of the second map to the new map

The result of the method will be a map with elements :
"a" : true
"c" : false

How can I reduce the amount of code by replacing loops and conditions with Stream API and lambda expressions?

Comment: Are the keys of the two maps guaranteed to be the same? What do you want to happen if they aren’t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s OK to modify the original `b`, you don’t need a stream operation, **EDIT:** just use `removeAll()` (and if it isn’t OK, you may make a copy first).

```
    b.entrySet().removeAll(a.entrySet());
    System.out.println(b);
```

Output is what you said you wanted:

> {a=true, c=false}

Thanks to Eritrean for suggesting `removeAll` rather than `removeIf`, an obvious improvement.

If you need to make a copy in order not to modify the original `b`, I suggest

```
    Map<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<>(b);
    result.entrySet().removeAll(a.entrySet());
```

Comment: I would here suggest `removeAll` instead of `removeIf`, which reduces the need for comparison. `b.entrySet().removeAll(a.entrySet());    return b;`

Comment: @Eritrean An obviously good suggestion, thank you very much. I have edited.

Answer (score 3):

Stream the second `Map` and collect all entries which are having different values than the first `Map`

```
Map<String, Boolean> result = b.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().equals(a.get(entry.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Map<String, Boolean> a = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Boolean> b = new HashMap<>();

        a.put("a", false);
        a.put("b", true);
        a.put("c", true);

        b.put("a", true);
        b.put("b", true);
        b.put("c", false);

        Map<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<>();

        
        a.keySet().stream()
            .filter(b::containsKey)
            .filter(key -> a.get(key) != b.get(key))
            .forEach(key -> result.put(key, b.get(key)));
        ;
        
        System.out.println(result);
        
    }
```